# Citing - how to get pp. 78.

Tags: biblatex, citing

I often want to cite with pp.78, denoting page 78 and following. Is there a way to do that directly in a way of `\autocite[78]{title}`?

Comment: You know that 'p' is usually for a single page and 'pp' for a range of pages?

Comment: Yes, but I've been taught that it is sufficient to cite the first page and use ff (in Germany) or pp. if the cite refers to the following pages as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write `\autocite[78\psq]{title}` or `\autocite[78\psqq]{title}`. See sections *3.7.8 Miscellaneous Commands* and *3.12.3 Page Numbers in Citations* of the biblatex manual for details.

EDIT: My answer may be the "usual" way to denote "following" pages, but it's not what you want. Write `\autocite[\ppno~78]{title}` to force a page range.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer... and sorry for not reading the manual good enough.