# Cite page ranges with "sq."/"f." and "sqq."/"ff."

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm using `biblatex` with `biber` as backend.

If I want to indicate that I cited over multiple consecutive pages, the German citation convention I need to follow is to add *f.* or *ff.* after the page number. For instance the output should something like this:

> vgl. Donald Ervin Knuth. The TEXbook. Addison-Wesley, 1986, S. 21 f.

Right now I'm exclusively using the `\footcite` command like this: `\footcite[vgl.][21]{Knuth1986}`. Adding the *f.* or just *f* inside the brackets with the page number doesn't work, If I do that the *S.* for page disappears. Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@Book{Knuth1986,
    Title                    = {The \TeX book},
    Author                   = {Donald~Ervin Knuth},
    Publisher                = {Addison-Wesley},
    Year                     = {1986}
}

\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

Some text. \footcite[vgl.][21]{Knuth1986}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11811/35864

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\psq` for "sq."/"f." and `\psqq` for "sqq."/"ff.". `biblatex` will automatically recognise those commands as part of a page range and will add the page prefix "p."/"pp."/"S." appropriately.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knuth1986,
  title     = {The {\TeX} book},
  author    = {Donald Ervin Knuth},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year      = {1986},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text.\autocite[vgl.][21\psq]{Knuth1986}
Some text.\autocite[vgl.][21\psqq]{Knuth1986}
\end{document}
```

[image: vgl. Donald Ervin Knuth. The TeX book. Addison-Wesley, 1986, S. 21 f.//vgl. ebd., S. 21 ff.]